# CRegKey crash on old Windows XP

Tags: c++, windows, vb.net

I created a DLL in Visual Studio 2017, which  opens a registry key and take a string as variant. Here a code extraction...

```
===================== C++ LIBRARY CODE ==================================
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <math.h>
#include <vector>
#include <oaidl.h>
#include <oleauto.h>
#include <atlstr.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <comdef.h>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <regex>
#include <ppl.h>
#include <mutex>

VARIANT _stdcall xxx_Version_Get()

{
CRegKey Key;
CString sValue;
VARIANT Str;
Str.vt = VT_BSTR;

LONG nA = Key.Open(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, _T([registry name omitted]), KEY_READ);   
ULONG nValueLength = 0;

LONG nB = Key.QueryStringValue(_T("Version"), NULL, &nValueLength);

if (nValueLength > 0) LONG nC = Key.QueryStringValue(_T("Version"), sValue.GetBufferSetLength(nValueLength - 1), &nValueLength); 

Str.bstrVal = sValue.AllocSysString();
return Str;
}
```

Due to the DLL is used on various machines (some of them with the old Windows XP) I compiled for x86 and with Windows_XP compatibility.

When I call the DLL from a Visual Basic script installed on Windows XP, the program crashes. Here the code...

```
 =========== Visual Basic on Windows XP =========================
 Private Declare Function xxx_Version_Get Lib "Test.dll" () As Variant

Sub Main
  Dim Test As Variant

  Test = xxx_Version_Get()
End Sub
```

On windows XP machine is installed Service Pack 2 and Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable 2015 v14.0.23026. I investigated the problem and the VB crashes  at the line

```
CRegKey Key;
```

In the end, In order to verify the source of the problem (Visual Studio or Windows XP), I tried also to compile the dummy function SUM (a+b = c). This function works on XP.

I'm quite sure that the problem is something about the ATL class family (CRegKey is part of it) or something missing on XP.

In the end, I have no problems if I call the same library on Windows 7 Platform.

Comment: Windows version 6 (aka Vista) has a counter-measure against the off-by-one bugs that are so common when reading strings from the registry.    Using -1 is not correct, you have to leave space for the string terminator.